# Replacement seatpost clamp for Saturae seatpost

Tags: road-bike, saddle, seatpost

I have destroyed the clamp that connects the seatpost with the saddle on my Mekk.

The seatpost is Saturae.

Can someone tell me what type of clamp i need and where I can get it? Its a one bolt seat post and a standard rail saddle.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to provide a picture.  Some Saturae posts appear to be bog-standard, others appear to have a specialized clamp.  (At the very least visit your local bike shop and ask if they have something that fits.)

Comment: Voting to close as too broad, we need pictures.  Will retract vote if you add photos.

Comment: It's probably best to contact Saturae if its not a standard (non-suspension, non-dropper, etc.) seatpost and get a replacement part. If it is a standard seatpost, you can just pickup a replacement seatpost for probably cheaper -- last one I bought was some cheap Kalloy one which was like 15 bucks at my LBS.

Comment: Thanks guys. Going to buy another seatpost of the same diameter,